# Understanding Angular routing at feature module

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have routing defined as so in my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
[
   {path: 'xyz', loadChildren: './child/child.module#ChildModule'}
]
```

and in `child-routing.module.ts` as

```
[
    {path: '', component: ChildComponent},
    {path: ':id', component: ChildComponent}
]
```

When I visit the route `localhost:4200/xyz` it loads the `ChildComponent` which is expected.

But when I go to `localhost:4200/` it loads the `ChildComponent`. This wasn't expected as I assumed it is parent_route i.e `xyz` plus child_route.

How do I restrict angular from loading `ChildComponent` on `/`

Example posted on StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xts7bc

Comment: Post a complete minimal example, as a stackblitz, reproducing the issue. My guess is that you imported the child module in your root module.

Comment: @JBNizet Have updated the question with stackblitz example

Comment: Just as I suspected: you're importing your child module in parent module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `lazy-load` the `ParentModule` and the `ChildModule`, but you have imported both of them, in `AppModule` and `ParentModule` respectively. The router are not matching to the defined routes in Parent and AppModule, but they match the ChildModule, hence you get that component even on the root ('/').

To fix this, remove the `ParentModule` from the imports array of `AppModule` and remove `ChildModule` from the imports of `ParentModule`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It says can't find the module.

Comment: Well, that was weird. I restarted `ng serve` and everything is fine now. @Sachin